# Child control in ActiveX control moving when scrolling sheet in Excel

Tags: c++, excel, winapi, mfc, activex

Today I Created simple ActiveX MFC Control. My purpose is to insert this control in an Excel sheet and to create a child control with margin (or set the padding of ActiveX). I cannot user C# and windows forms control for that(only c++, this is project requirements)

I Create simple MFC ActiveX control and exported 1 function - SetContent(HWND newContent) that supposed to inject any window in my ActiveX control. I want that window to be shown with the margin.

https://pasteboard.co/I74MTVN.png - this is how control looks like at the beginning

https://pasteboard.co/I74NW7T.png - this is how it looks when i start scrolling my sheet

As you can see child control(light green) is moving when i scroll

```
void MyActiveXControl::SetContent(OLE_HANDLE newContent)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    if (this->m_lReadyState == READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
    {
        if (newContent != 0)
        {
            ::SetParent(HWND(newContent), this->GetSafeHwnd());
            int width, height;
            this->GetControlSize(&width, &height);
            ::MoveWindow(HWND(newContent), 10, 10, width - 20, height - 20, 0);
            m_content = HWND(newContent);
        }
    }
}
```

this is only one pease of code that doing manipulations with control (in SetContent method)

This is Paint:

```
void MyActiveXControl::OnPaint()
{
    CRect rcBounds;
    CPaintDC pdc(this);
    this->GetClientRect(&rcBounds);
    pdc.FillRect(rcBounds, CBrush::FromHandle((HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH)));
}
```

What I tried :

1) SetWindowPos instead of MoveWindow with different flags such as NOSIZE, NOMOVE and etc.

2) Overriding of OnSize message - there is a problem that on size event fires 2 times per 1 scroll:

```
 1. With actual ActiveX control size (width: 500, height: 500) 
 2. With the size of the area that is visible (width: 500, height: 250)
```

How can I fix my issue and prevent child control from moving inside of ActiveX control?

Comment: Hi Win, if `HWND(newContent)` is the handle of your child control(light green) while which window handle do you get from `this->GetSafeHwnd()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I getting my ActiveX control window handle (the black one). this - is a pointer to my ActiveX control that is inherited from COleControl class

Comment: So it is ActiveX control window moving inside of Excel window, not "child control moving inside of ActiveX control". Have you set the parent window of ActiveX control?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT ActiveX control stays on its position(only half of it is visible on the second screenshot) And as you can see the bottom of my "border" is overridden by the child that is moving when scrolling sheet.